# how to add calculated columns while joining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, group-by

My first dataframe is like this df1

```
Name 
Jack
Brad
Jennifer
```

Second dataframe df2 like this

```
Name        value  
Jack         1
Jack         1
Jack         3
Brad.        2
Brad.        2
Jennifer.
```

I want to achieve this df3

count No of 1's for a single name as cat_1.
count No of 2's for a single name as cat_2.
count No of 3's for a single name as cat_3.
if there is no value for a name then 0.

```
Name     cat_1    cat_2    cat_3
Jack.      2        0        1
Brad.      0        2        0
jennifer.  0        0        0
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, `pivot` and `merge`:

```
(df1
 .merge(pd.crosstab(df2['Name'], df2['value'].convert_dtypes()).add_prefix('cat_'),
        left_on='Name', right_index=True, how='left'
         )
 .fillna(0)
)
```

output:

```
       Name  cat_1  cat_2  cat_3
0      Jack    2.0    0.0    1.0
1      Brad    0.0    2.0    0.0
2  Jennifer    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

Comment: thank for the answer. However i am getting lot of cat columns instead of cat_1, cat_2, cat_3. I am getting upto 100 cat columns. Do u have any idea?

Comment: i am expecting output of jack with cat_1 is 2, cat_2 is 0, cat_3 is 1. Because no of  1's for jack is 2 and No of 2's is 0 and No of 3's is 1.

Comment: @Nithin then you must provide a logic in the question

Comment: See update, but again, only **guessing** what you might want